# Forward Gmail Including the attachments using gmail api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gmail-api

I want to forward gmail including the attachments, currently it only forwards email without attachments.

```
const handleForwardMsg = (forwardTo, headers, body) => {
  let email = "";
  email += `From: ${getHeader(headers, "From")} \r\n`;
  email += `Date: ${getHeader(headers, "Date")} \r\n`;
  email += `Subject: ${getHeader(headers, "Subject")} \r\n`;
  email += `To: ${forwardTo} \r\n`;
  email += `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 \r\n`;
  email += `\r\n ${body}`;

  sendMessage("me", email, displayToast);
};
```

This is event which occurs on submit

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const form = e.target;
  const forwardTo = form.elements["emailTo"].value;
  handleForwardMsg(
    forwardTo,
    forwardData.payload.headers,
    getMessageBody(forwardData.payload)
  );
  onClose();
};
```

And here is the `sendmessage` function.

```
const sendMessage = (userId, email, callback) => {
  const base64EncodedEmail = Base64.encodeURI(email);
  const request = window.gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
    userId: userId,
    resource: {
      raw: base64EncodedEmail,
    },
  });
  request.execute(callback);
};
```

Comment: I see that you are not attaching the attachments to your message. The files would get there itself I believe you have to download them and then insert in the message as you would normally do (forwarding or not).